# C++:How to define a base class constructor inside the derived class,if the base constructor has initialization list with private members

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following base class A in a c++ library:
in the a.h header file:

```
class A
{ 
private:
    double param1_;
    B* param2_; //Another library class
    void function();
public:
  A();
}
```

in the corresponding a.cpp source file the following implementation exists:

```
A::A() :
  param1_(1.0),
  param2_(NULL)
  {
  function();
  }

void A::function(){

    some code
}
```

And i want to create a class B which inherits class A, and define the constructor of class A implicitly inside the constructor of derived class B. I am a little bit confused with the initialization list in the implementation of class A constructor. I wrote:

in the b.h:

```
class B:: public A{
public B();
}
```

How should i define the base class constructor in the in the b.cpp file??

Also how should i implicitly define base class constructor inside the derived class constructor, since base class private function is called inside the constructor?

Comment: `public B();` is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`B.h`:

```
class B: public A{
public:
 B();
}
```

`B.cpp`:

```
B::B() : A(parameters) {}
```

Comment: It does not work, the following error is produced:  A::A()  A(); candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided

Comment: @juls Well yes,if the constructor of `A` takes no parameters then don't pass in any.